# After export datagridview to csv skipping one column data and writing in next column in C#

Tags: c#

Exported my `datagrid` data to csv but after exported one line data moved to next line.

```
internal void ExtractDataToCSV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    try
    {
        var fDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        fDialog.Filter = "csv Files (*.csv,*.csv)|*.csv;*.csv";
        if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fDialog.FileName))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fDialog.FileName);
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                sw.Write(",");
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dr.Cells[i].Value);
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void BtnExprt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.Rows.Count !=0)
    {
        ObjCsvFileIO.ExtractDataToCSV(dgv);
    }
}
```

After Exported output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the "," that you are putting after the last element of the line.

Try that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText);
            if( i < dgv.Columns.Count-1 ) sw.Write(",");
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dr.Cells[i].Value);
                if( i < dgv.Columns.Count-1 ) sw.Write(",");
            }
```